# Wordpress wp-config file better security

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server

I have few questions regarding the wp-config.php file in Wordpress. I moved the file from the wordpress installation directory, above the www directory and inside one of the home folders. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/improve-wordpress-securitty-wp-config-php-location/). In the main wordpress directory i added another wp-config.php file with the following include path:

```
<?php
include('/home/www/web55438/files/wp-config.php');
?>
```

Inside the files folder i also added the following .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#Prevend directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

#Protect files from displaying
<Files wp-config.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

#Protect htaccess file
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
   order allow,deny
   deny from all
   satisfy all
</Files>
```

My questions are: Is this a secure way for handling the wp-config.php file with an absolute path? Is the .htaccess file configured properly? And what would you change for better wordpress security?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Files wp-config.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

change it to

```
<Files wp-config.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>
```

This way, you are denying access to wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

As you are moving your config file from default location to location above your root of website. Then this is proper way to include that file

Regarding adding more security, follow stuff posted by Vhortex in one of the questions.